# Adding Greek letters and variables to a legend in plot R

Tags: r

I want to print the variables z in the plot.
I have added

sprintf(%1.1f,z[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyR1e.png))

etc in various combinations with paste (and paste0) and expression, but none of them are working.

In the dummy code below I have hardcoded the values I want to see.

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(1,2,3)
plot(x,y)
z <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3)
labels = c( expression( paste( sigma," = ","0.1" )),
            expression( paste( sigma," = ","0.2" )),
            expression( paste( sigma," = ","0.3" ))
           )
legend("topright", inset=.05, title="title",
   labels, lwd=2, lty=c(1,1,1), col=colors)
```

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the string and parse it.

```
labels <- parse(text = sprintf("sigma == %f", z))
```

Words can be separated with ~ symbols or combined into a single literal using quotes.  * can be used for juxtaposition.

```
labels <- parse(text = sprintf("Case ~ (%d) ~ sigma == %f", 1:3, z))

labels <- parse(text = sprintf("Case ~ (%d) * ':' ~ sigma == %f", 1:3, z))

labels <- parse(text = sprintf("'Case (%d)' ~ sigma == %f", 1:3, z))

labels <- parse(text = sprintf("'Case (%d):' ~ sigma == %f", 1:3, z))
```

Try `demo("plotmath")` for more info.

Comment: Thanks that works. How about if I want to have a string " Case (1) sigma == %f" that won't work. how do you do that?

Comment: Have moved comments to answer.